# Can't solve simple coupled differential equations with well known analytic solution

Tags: differential-equations

These coupled differential equations have the well-known solutions of Bessel forms functions. I am trying to find these solutions using Mathematica 10.0 but it doesn't work:

```
p1 = Function[{f, \[Rho]}, (D[f, \[Rho]] +  m/\[Rho] f)];
p2 = Function[{f, \[Rho]}, (D[f, \[Rho]] - (m - 1)/\[Rho] f )];
eqs1 = p2[
x[\[Rho]], \[Rho]] - (\[Epsilon] + \[CapitalDelta]) y[\[Rho]];
eqs2 = p1[
y[\[Rho]], \[Rho]] + (\[Epsilon] - \[CapitalDelta]) x[\[Rho]];
DSolve[{eqs1 == 0, eqs2 == 0}, {x[\[Rho]], y[\[Rho]]}, \[Rho]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know why Mathematica can't solve it directly.

If you eliminate `y[\[Rho]]` MMA solves the ode 2nd order

```
 eqs2 == 0  /.y -> Function[\[Rho],Evaluate[y[\[Rho]] /. Solve[eqs1 == 0, y[\[Rho]]][[1]]]]
 DSolve[%, x, \[Rho]]
 (*{{x -> Function[{\[Rho]}, 
BesselJ[-1 + 
    m, -I Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta]^2 - \[Epsilon]^2] \[Rho]] C[1] + 
 BesselY[-1 + 
    m, -I Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta]^2 - \[Epsilon]^2] \[Rho]] C[2]]}}*)
```